# Statement for Searching for a variable and changing it

Tags: sql

I hope I could possibly get some help with the problem I am having. Now before I continue I must say I don't have a lot knowledge about SQL or programming in general. I am just getting into it and I might not provide all the necessary information.

Anyways, I am trying to create a statement in SQL that will allow me to add a decimal point to the following number "775" to "77.5".

So I tried a number of variations and at first I thought it would be a simple.

```
IF ? = "775" SELECT "77.5"
SELECT REPLACE ( ?, "775", "77.5")
```

and a number of frustration other instances.

I believe that I need to declare that the data I am pulling is an integer, however I am not sure how. I have looked at tutorials and tried some of them and still not luck. If anyone could give me any advice to get on the track to achieving this. That would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a number or a string?

Comment: If the variable is stored as an integer in the DB, I don't think you can change to a decimal number without altering the table.

Answer (score 0):

hm.. you indicate SQL so:

this would be an `UPDATE` statement - you want to change some data in the database.

it goes something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myvalue = 77.5 WHERE myvalue = 775;
```

or a bit more general for more updates all at once:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myvalue = myvalue/10 WHERE myvalue > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = 77.5
WHERE column1 = 775;
```

Have a look at the [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement:

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @int INT

SET @int = 775

SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(@int AS VARCHAR(4)), 1, 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@int AS VARCHAR(4)), 3, 1)